# install4j service has 2 processes in task manager?

Tags: install4j

After upgrading from install4j 4x to 5.x, install4j services now have 2 processes in task manager for each configured service. Witn install4j4, there was one process in task manager for each service.

One of them is  about 1,500 K and the other is what I expect our application to use (100+ MB).
The services run as System user.

So for a service called "DataEngineService" the following is in task manager:
DataEngineService.exe System 1,500K
DataEngineService.exe System 123,432K

Is this related to "elevation of Privileges" and normal, or is this unexpected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional. With one process is was not possible to handle JVM shutdown hooks reliably. In install4j 4.x, there were lots of problems related to JVM shutdown hooks which are now solved in install4j 5.x.